# I have Multiple radio button with same name in it of array and have same values as 1

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have multiple radio button name in array with same values as 1 for all.
I need want to get if uncheck means set as zero how can I do that. Below is my code

check image [its sample image but same form like i having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSY0H.png) :

*html code* :

```
<input type="radio" name="radio_name[]" id="radi_name" value="1" checked >
<label for="radio1">Set as Default</label>
```

*PHP code* :

```
$a[]=$_post['radio_name'];
prinr_r($a);
```

*Current result* :

```
Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

*Expected result* :

```
Array ( [0] => 1,[1] => 0,[2] => 0,[3] => 0 )
```

I have checked one radio button only, rest all need to zero.

Comment: So use checkbox instead or radio.

Comment: it would appear this is working as designed - use javascript to send all the radio buttons with zero values

Comment: but user need to check one box in form if i use checkbox multiple box can be checked

Comment: Do not use all bold while asking question. Bold only for specific highlighting

Comment: `$_post` is mostly always empty, it's `$_POST`. Then, maybe read up on what radio buttons do and how they are handled. You won't get values for all radiobuttons since only the one checked will be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

use it like.

```
    <form method='post' id='userform' action='test2.php'> <tr>
        <td>Trouble Type</td>
        <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' class="check" value='1'>1<br>
        <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' class="check"  value='1'>2<br>
        <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]'  class="check"  value='1'>3
        </td> </tr> </table> <input type='button' class='buttons'> </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.buttons').click(function(){
                var checkbox_arr = [];
                $('.check').each(function(){
                    checkbox_arr.push(+$(this).is( ':checked' ));
                });
                console.log(checkbox_arr);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: dude value is need to be same for all checkbox or radio button

Comment: I have edit the answer you can use jquery for the same and then post this array in ajax request.